# IdeaVim with Jupyter Notebook on PyCharm

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm, jupyter-notebook, ideavim

I am trying out IntelliJ. I have installed the Python plugin, and IdeaVim.

I cannot navigate properly across Jupyter Notebook cells using `hj`. I mean, on normal mode, I cannot go to the next (or previous) cell, even if there is one, using `hj`.

Is there a way to do it without the mouse, possibly rebindable? I have read the tutorial and tried to find something in the program, but could not.

Answer (score 5):

Ideavim plugin doesn't seem to support Pycharm's notebook implementation as of right now :(

There's an open [issue marked as "bug" on Ideavim's issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-1030) that was opened back in 2015 and it seems like it doesn't have any progress made since.
However according to the comment in the issue thread you can:

> funny way to get into the command mode is type something so that the suggestion panel appears, now press "esc" you will get into Vim command mode

So this might indicate that this could be solved and updated in the future.

As an alternative you can try out [`jupyter-vim-binding`](https://github.com/lambdalisue/jupyter-vim-binding), however it doesn't work with Pycharm either.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion panel trick. i did that accidentally and couldn't figure out what i had done.